# Can I root locked Droid 3 and flash Cyanogen

Tags: rooting, cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-3

Before I purchase a Droid 3 from hong kong , I would like to know if I can apply the recently discovered root exploit on a locked phone that i can purchase there.

Pardon my ignorance in this locked phone area because I have rooted  phones here in india but all were available as unlocked devices.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am know, CyanogenMod is not yet available for the Droid 3. While there maybe someone working on bringing it to that device, it currently is not "supported". You can look at the [Wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Latest_Version), I think it is one of the more updated pages for supported devices, but then again, it also hasn't been updated since January.

The "most accurate" sites to see if a device is supported is the [CM-Nightly Changelog](http://cm-nightlies.appspot.com/) site and the [Download site](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/).

The nightly changelog site may show devices, but that doesn't mean they actually have a "stable" version. You would have to check the download site to see if there is a stable version. But as I said, I don't see the Droid 3 on there right now. I believe the "codename" for the Droid 3 is the "Targa"

I do want to add, that if you know of a way to root then rooting the device should be possible, you just wont be able to flash CM7 (for now).

Comment: Thank Ryan.. If I get a locked device can I still root it using the current adb rooting procedure thats floating around

Comment: I am not sure what the rooting method is for the device, but I think that just about every device has been rooted one way or another.